# should be a maximum of 30 days between two dates

Tags: node.js, joi

I need to validate 2 parameters, as you see below. Validation should be like this:

```
 startDate - endDate < 30 days
```

```
  startDate: Joi.date().default(new Date()),
  endDate: Joi.date().default(new Date()),
```

And when I do like that, I am getting an error.

```
Joi.object({
  startDate: Joi.date().default(new Date()),
  endDate: Joi.date().less(Joi.ref('startDate') + 50000).default(new Date()),
})
// error - AssertError: date must have a valid date format or reference
```

I am trying to add validation to 2 date parameters.

Comment: What is `50000` here? Milliseconds?

Comment: I put that for dummy miliseconds, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Joi.ref's [`adjust`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#refkey-options) option along with js date's [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

**adjust** allows to manipulate referenced value (startDate) before doing the validation.

**getTime** returns the date in milliseconds so we can add milliseconds to it.

```
const t = Joi.object({
  startDate: Joi.date().default(new Date()),
  endDate: Joi.date()
              .less(
                   Joi.ref("startDate", {
                            adjust: (v) => v.getTime() + (29 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
                   })
               )
               .default(new Date()),
  });
```